# How to plot subplots in column order in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In this code below each subplot gets added to next ***row***, How can I change the ordering to follow ***columns***?

```py
for i in range(1,20):
    plt.subplot(10,2,i)
    ...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-to-plot-in-multiple-subplots

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054631/fill-matplotlib-subplots-by-column-not-row

Comment: @JodyKlymak, the answer provided by HMH1013 was what I was looking for.